# Running a servlet on a maven application

Tags: jquery, maven, jakarta-ee

I am having a maven application which uses bootstrap, angular js, jsp on front end and has a form on submit of same a email must be triggered using jQuery ajax to communicate with servlet and send an email with form details, here the issue is in jQuery Url part the servlet needs to be given, tried providing "Loan/MainServletPath" but not working.....So my question is how can i communicate between jQuery and Servlet in maven application.....

```
Help to resolve this would  be appreciated...
```

Comment: **maven application**.....what r u talking about?

Comment: Maven is "just" a way to manage your application folder structure, compilation, testing, deployment, plus loads of extra good things; but it has nothing to do with you application logic and / or runtime behaviour, so it has nothing to do with your issue.